# java JDBC : Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow

Tags: java, jdbc

Hi I am getting the bwlow error while running my JAVA code

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.throwOverflow(NumberCommonAccessor.java:4380) ~[ojdbc-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getInt(NumberCommonAccessor.java:111) ~[ojdbc-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getObject(NumberCommonAccessor.java:3263) ~[ojdbc-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarnumAccessor.getObject(T4CVarnumAccessor.java:303) ~[ojdbc-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.getObject(OracleCallableStatement.java:2049) ~[ojdbc-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.getObject(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:815) ~[ojdbc-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
```

Comment: Looks like you number is to big for an int. Use a Long instead

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Already using Long in the outputMapper. The DB column is Number(18), the generated number by the store proc is of the 13 digits. Up to 12 digits its working, but when stored proc startd producing 13 digit number the code is failing.

Answer (score 6):

In Oracle, if you store numeric data and this data is out of range from column data type then you got this type of Exception.

Example- if you have a column of INTEGER(NUMBER) type and you store data greater than 2,147,483,647 then its Numeric Overflow.

Comment: The column data type is NUMBER(18) , while the generated number is of 13 digits.Can you please suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I use " Types.BIGINT" instead of "Types.NUMERIC" in java code. and the problem solved