# Numeric overflow error after upgrading to Spring 3.1.0 & Java 17

Tags: spring, upgrade

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.throwOverflow(NumberCommonAccessor.java:4161)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getInt(NumberCommonAccessor.java:131)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getInt(GeneratedStatement.java:171)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getInt(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:269)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getInt(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.IntegerJdbcType$2.doExtract(IntegerJdbcType.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.readCurrentRowValues(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:267)
    ... 157 common frames omitted
```

Please suggest some solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java JDBC : Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642726/java-jdbc-caused-by-java-sql-sqlexception-numeric-overflow)

Comment: Thanks for your response but they didnt mention whats the root cause for this behaviour  in latest version of Spring & hibernate .. same code was working fine in the lower version of Spring 2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same issue but it worked after upgrading to Spring Boot 3.1.1 which was released recently.

Comment: Thanks Bruna. Yes thats right it could be a bug in lower versions.